Sitecore Core database location of the "Publish All Items" item in the Publishing Dashboard
Could you please let me know the Sitecore Core database location of the "Publish All Items" item in the Publishing Dashboard ? 

Publish All Items inside the publishing dashboard, is generated from Button Rendering inside the /sitecore/client/Applications/Publishing/Dashboard in the core database as below.

Inside this button contains the reference to the configuration item /sitecore/client/Applications/Publishing/Common/System/ConfigurationItems/ButtonPublishInstance from which the text is rendered on the button.

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

Thank you for finding the presentation details. I was looking into the exact item path for "Publish All Items" to manage permissions on it.
Here is the path:
"/sitecore/client/Applications/Publishing/Common/System/ConfigurationItems/BorderFullRePublishSecurity"

It is at path - /sitecore/system/Settings/Publishing/Publish All Items in Core Database
This item is part of the publishing configuration in Sitecore and is crucial for managing publishing workflows and settings.

The path is invalid. We can use the following response from ckhanna for this. thankyou.

The respective paths can be found under:
/sitecore/client/Applications/Publishing/PublishAllItem
Related items :
 1. /sitecore/client/Applications/Publishing/Dashboard 
    
 2. /sitecore/client/Applications/Publishing/Common/System/ConfigurationItems/BorderFullRePublishSecurity 
    
 3. /sitecore/client/Applications/Publishing/Common/System/ConfigurationItems/ButtonPublishInstance

